# How to create a generator function that produces a specific number of values?

Tags: python, generator

I am trying to create a generator function that accepts 1 or 1+ arguments. It should return an iterable of the left overvalues of the iterable with the most values after the other iterabless no longer produce values.

For example:

```
 for i in func('dfg', 'dfghjk', [1,2]):
    print(i)

prints -> h
          j
          k
```

because the argument 'dfg', which has the second most values, stop producing values at 3.
  The argument 'dfghjk', which has the most values, then yields 'hjk' (the leftover values).

The catch here is that the iterables may or may not be finite, so I am not able to compute the length of the argument or add it to other data structures.

Any help would be great, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve your problem I'd try to manually exhaust all the iterators until only one remains.

```py
def foo(*iterables):
    iterators = [iter(x) for x in iterables]
    while len(iterators) > 1:
        for idx, it in enumerate(iterators[:]):
            try:
                peek = next(it)
            except StopIteration:
                # remove the iterator when exhausted
                iterators.pop(idx)

    yield peek
    yield from iterators[0]
```

Notice that for it to work you will need to ensure that the iterables are indeed iterators (converting them with `iter`). You also need to store the last element obtained from the iterator. Notice that because we only use the iterator interface infinite iterators work just fine:

```py
>>> it = func([1], itertools.count(), [2,2])
>>> for _ in range(3): print(next(it))
2
3
4
```

Comment: OHHH I see. So when an iterator raised the StopIteration, we pop it out of the iterators list to exhaust the list. But, what does yield from iterators[0] do?

Comment: Oh I got it. Yield from meaning you only want to yield the values from the iterators list, which would only be the iterator that is left because all others were popped. Thanks so much!

Comment: Correct! I would recommend you to look into the [itertools](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html) module if you ever need to do involved things with iterators, for most of the use cases you can use one of the solutions there.